# how to setup exoplayer to play both mp4 and m3u8 depends on url ending

Tags: android, exoplayer, m3u8

can you guys tell me how to play m3u8 and mp4 video with a single play button in exoplayer android studio.
my app run using JSON retrofit where my URL is coming from. it connects to recycler adapter and array and that goes to intent via intent I am calling URL or URI to play the file .

I am able to use either m3u8 code or mp4 code but I don't know how to implement both in one java file inside the button

for m3u8 i am using :

```html
LoadControl LoadControls = new DefaultLoadControl();
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        ExoTrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new
                AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory();
        trackSelector = new
                DefaultTrackSelector(VideoPortrait.this, videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        DefaultRenderersFactory renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(this);
        renderersFactory.setExtensionRendererMode(DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER);
        simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this, renderersFactory)
                .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
                .build();
        videoPlayer.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "ChristianGospelApp"));
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(mp4Url)));

        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

For mp4 i am using (in another activity i tried it as trailer activity)

```html
private void setUpExoplayer(String mp4Url) {

        LoadControl LoadControls = new DefaultLoadControl();
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        ExoTrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new
                AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory();
        trackSelector = new
                DefaultTrackSelector(VideoPlayerActivity.this, videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        DefaultRenderersFactory renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(this);
        renderersFactory.setExtensionRendererMode(DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER);
        simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this, renderersFactory)
                .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
                .build();
        videoPlayer.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "ChristianGospelApp"));
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(mp4Url)));

        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set mime type to M3U8 or MP4 when creating media item. Like this,

When creating mp4 media,

```
val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
            .setUri(Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("videoUri")))
            .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MP4)
            .build()
```

Change mime type to Application_M3U8 in setMimeType method for M3U8 video.

Comment: I have also added my coding @Vaibhav Goyal

Comment: I've tried this using Application_M3U8 but I still get the error "No suitable media source factory found for content type: 2" (type 2 is M3U8)

Comment: ExoPlayer is a fast developing library and different versions can contain breaking changes so post it as a different question with all the relevant code snippets.